# first element in data frame between two values

Tags: r

I have a data frames `df` that looks like this:

```
Frame      BodyPart Likelihood
1    907     Nose  0.9538603
2    1240    Mouth  0.9962518
3    200    Mouth  0.9963566
4    1242    Mouth  0.9968582
10   1279    Mouth  0.9953254
11   12000    Mouth  0.9945236
12   14690    Mouth  0.9947007
13   1283    Mouth  0.9932089
14   1291    Mouth  0.9921902
15   17777    Mouth  0.9912276
16   1293    Mouth  0.9907160
17   13100    Mouth  0.9837915
```

and a data frame showing the start frame of four conditions:

```
> condition
  condition frame
1        C1     0
2        C2  7796
3        C3 11165
4        C4 14687
```

and I would like to extract the first frame value from `df` within each condition. Something like

```
  First_C1 First_C2 First_C3 First_C4
1 200      9107      12000    14690
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of rolling join. In `dplyr`, you can use `closest` with `join_by`:

```r
library(dplyr)
condition %>% 
  left_join(df, join_by(closest(frame <= Frame)))

#   condition frame Frame BodyPart Likelihood
# 1        C1     0   200    Mouth  0.9963566
# 2        C2  7796  9107     Nose  0.9538603
# 3        C3 11165 12000    Mouth  0.9945236
# 4        C4 14687 14690    Mouth  0.9947007
```

Comment: Nice. I have tried to do a rolling join with data.table: `library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt1 <- as.data.table(df)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df1 %>%  select(Frame = frame, everything()))

setkey(dt1, Frame)
setkey(dt2, Frame)

result <- dt1[dt2, roll = Inf]` But I do not get C1 = 200 I get C1 = 0?